# Dynamic image assigned to live tile does not show?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, live-tile

I have a Windows Store app written in C# that works with photos.  I want to show the last photo the user selected in the app in the medium size live tile (150 x 150).  I am using the code below to do it.  When I run the app I don't get any errors, but I don't see the selected photo in the live tile either.  I know that I am doing at least some things right.  I say this because if the user hasn't selected a photo yet, then I show a test image and I do see that image in the tile.  But the test image comes from the app package using the *ms-appx* protocol, not from the app storage area.

I found a few SO posts on the subject but they are all for Windows Phone.  I looked at the *KnownFolders* list for Windows Store app files, but nothing seemed to map to the *SharedContent* folder required for files meant for live tile use in Windows Phone.  What is wrong with my code?

Note, the **vvm.ActiveVideomark.GetThumbnail()** call simply retrieves a bitmap as a *WriteableBitmap* object.  As you can see in the code, I am resizing the image to the size required by the Medium live tile (150 x 150).  **ToJpegFileAsync()** is an extension method that encodes a WriteableBitmap object to jpeg bytes and then writes those bytes to a file using the given file name.  Both of these calls are well-tested and are not the source of the problem as far as I know.

```
        TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Clear();
        TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().EnableNotificationQueue(true);

        var tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare150x150Image);

        var tileImage = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("image")[0] as XmlElement;

        // Got a current photo?
        if (vvm.ActiveVideomark == null)
            // No, just show the regular logo image.
            tileImage.SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.scale-100.png");
        else
        {
            // Resize it to the correct size.
            WriteableBitmap wbm = await vvm.ActiveVideomark.GetThumbnail();
            WriteableBitmap wbm2 = wbm.Resize(150, 150, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);

            // Write it to a file so we can pass it to the Live Tile.
            string jpegFilename = "LiveTile1.jpg";
            StorageFile jpegFile = await wbm2.ToJpegFileAsync(jpegFilename);

            // Yes, show the selected image.
            tileImage.SetAttribute("src", jpegFile.Path);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The src attribute must contain a URI with ms-appx:///, ms-appdata:///local, or http[s]:// schemes. The StorageFile.Path property, as you're using with jpegFile.Path, is a local filesystem pathmame like c:\users\Robert\AppData... which won't be valid. So create your tile images in local app data, and then use ms-appdata:///local/ to refer to them in tile payloads.